# Control many Visual Studio debugger sessions from one

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, automation

I am writing a VSPackage and want to support starting multiple debugger sessions with a single keypress. Does anyone have any insight into how I can get access to another process's IServiceProvider? Each debugging session runs in it's own Visual Studio process instance.

I'm targeting Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kirill’s blog post outlines how to connect to another instance of VS here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2011/08/10/how-to-get-dte-from-visual-studio-process-id/

You can talk from another process to VS through all of the interfaces in the EnvDTE.dll once you have the DTE object from the Running Object Table.